# How to copy the content of a dictionary to another to clear the original one afterward

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to copy the content of a dictionary to another named tempDict, so that i can still use the data of the original dictionary, even with clearing the first dictionary, the original one. Both dictionary have the same type

I've tried the following

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>> tempDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>>(originalDict);

originalDict.Clear();
```

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>> tempDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>>();
tempDict = originalDict;

originalDict.Clear();
```

But it doesn't seems to work, but to me, both method create a new instance of a dictionary, and then assign the instance value to originalDict, since it's a new instance, even by deleting the originalDict, how could both be deleted ? i don't really understand this one, i'm probably wrong, but if anyone could explain, would be great.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do a foreach loop on `originalDict` and add items to `tempDict`

Comment: `new Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>(originalDict)`

Comment: There is no other way then ? @AleksAndreev

Comment: @canton7 The fact is that originalDict is also a Dictionary containing another Dictionary that contains a List as values, that's why i said they are the same type, by doing that, i'll just assign the innerDictionary of the tempDict to the originalDict right  ?

Comment: While the elements are copied this only a __shallow copy__ and clearing the original will clear the copies. You need to __copy deeper__! Using ToDictionary may help..

Comment: @Luxior you are in fact creating a new handle to the same instance of the dictionary. With the foreach loop, or use linq if you like it better, you are creating a new dictionary, that you put the same entry instances into. So you will not clear the new dictionary clearing to old, but still changing one of the entries in the old list will change the corresponding (= same) entry in the new list. Take a look a cloning and deep-cloning on this subject.

Comment: @Luxior another way is to use linq. Something like `tempDict = originalDict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToDtictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value.ToList()));`.

Comment: The shallow copy should be fine - `origDict.Clear()` should not affect `tempDict` and in my code it does not. Are you doing something else to the values in `origDict`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test code shows that the shallow copy of `origDict` to `tempDict` works fine:

```
Console.WriteLine(origDict.Count); // outputs 1

var tempDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>>(origDict);

Console.WriteLine(tempDict.Count); // outputs 1

origDict.Clear();

Console.WriteLine(origDict.Count); // outputs 0
Console.WriteLine(tempDict.Count); // outputs 1
```

Comment: Hmm indeed, it works, and i did / do nothing else with it, exept checking data in it... (i serialize in json) and when i posted this post, it serialized nothing but { } although there were data in origDict before the clear, and data in tempDict, dunno what happened, but that's for sure my bad, can't reproduce it though... Well anyway it's answered, thanks for the reply and the help !

Answer (score 0):

Same as NetMage but using the .Copy() method.

```
var origDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>>() { { "ABC", new Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>() { { 1, new List<dynamic>() { "xyx" } } } } };

Console.WriteLine(origDict.Count); // outputs 1
var tempDict = origDict.Copy();
Console.WriteLine(tempDict.Count); // outputs 1
origDict.Clear();
Console.WriteLine(origDict.Count); // outputs 0
Console.WriteLine(tempDict.Count); // outputs 1
```